# How do I get a random line from a file?

Tags: file, vector, io, rust

I'm trying to get a random line from a file:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
};

const FILENAME: &str = "/etc/hosts";

fn find_word() -> String {
    let f = File::open(FILENAME).expect(&format!("(;_;) file not found: {}", FILENAME));
    let f = BufReader::new(f);

    let lines: Vec<_> = f.lines().collect();

    let n = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, lines.len());
    let line = lines
        .get(n)
        .expect(&format!("(;_;) Couldn't get {}th line", n))
        .unwrap_or(String::from(""));

    line
}
```

This code doesn't work:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:18:16
   |
18 |       let line = lines
   |  ________________^
19 | |         .get(n)
20 | |         .expect(&format!("(;_;) Couldn't get {}th line", n))
   | |____________________________________________________________^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I tried adding `.clone()` before `.expect(...)` and before `.unwrap_or(...)` but it gave the same error.

Is there a better way to get a random line from a file that doesn't involve collecting the whole file in a `Vec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IteratorRandom::choose`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/seq/trait.IteratorRandom.html#method.choose) to randomly sample from an iterator using [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). This will scan through the entire file once, creating `String`s for each line, but it will not create a giant vector for every line:

```rust
use rand::seq::IteratorRandom; // 0.7.3
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
};

const FILENAME: &str = "/etc/hosts";

fn find_word() -> String {
    let f = File::open(FILENAME)
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("(;_;) file not found: {}: {}", FILENAME, e));
    let f = BufReader::new(f);

    let lines = f.lines().map(|l| l.expect("Couldn't read line"));

    lines
        .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
        .expect("File had no lines")
}
```

---

Your original problem is that:

1. [`slice::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get) returns an optional reference into the vector.

   You can either clone this or take ownership of the value:

   ```
   let line = lines[n].cloned()
   ```

   ```
   let line = lines.swap_remove(n)
   ```

   Both of these panic if `n` is out-of-bounds, which is reasonable here as you know that you are in bounds.
2. [`BufRead::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html) returns `io::Result<String>`, so you have to handle that error case.

Additionally, don't use `format!` with `expect`:

> ```
> expect(&format!("..."))
> ```

This will *unconditionally allocate memory*. When there's no failure, that allocation is wasted. Use `unwrap_or_else` as shown.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to get a random line from a file that doesn't involve collecting the whole file in a `Vec`?

You will always need to read the whole file, if only to know the number of lines. However, you don't need to store everything in memory, you can read lines one by one and discard them as you go so that you only keep one in the end. Here is how it goes:

- Read and store the first line;
- Read the second line, draw a random choice and either:

  - keep the first line with a probability of 50%,
  - or discard the first line and store the second line with a probability of 50%,
- Keep reading lines from the file and for line number `n`, draw a random choice and:

  - keep the currently stored line with a probability of `(n-1)/n`,
  - or replace the currently stored line with the current line with a probability of `1/n`.

Note that this is more or less what [`sample_iter`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.5.1/rand/seq/fn.sample_iter.html) does, except that `sample_iter` is more generic since it can work on any iterator and it can pick samples of any size (eg. it can choose `k` items randomly).